# Installing optional Nginx modules with yum

Tags: nginx, yum

I've installed ngninx with the basic: yum install nginx

But, it is missing a couple of modules that I need:
HttpHeadersModule
HttpGzipModule

How can I enable these modules at this point?

Comment: Check http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx3rdPartyModules and http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Official_Red_Hat.2FCentOS_packages

Comment: Don't mean to be dense, but this is telling me how to compile additional modules with nginx. In my case, yum has installed nginx and I need to add the modules after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx has no support for loadable modules. You should compile them in. (Or find a package where all of them would be already compiled in.)